# Cannot close gtk dialog window

Tags: python, gtk3

I am using gtk to create a file choose dialog:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import time

dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("World to load:", None,
                               Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
    (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
    Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

response = dialog.run()
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    print("load", dialog.get_filename())
else:
    print("cancel")

dialog.destroy()

time.sleep(5)
```

The code works: I get either file name or 'cancel printed.  But the chooser window does not close before the program exits 5s later.  The window just hangs there the program runs further and is responsive.  Replacing `dialog.destroy()` with `dialog.hide()` does not change anything as far as I can tell.

I get a warning:

```
Gtk-Message: 10:27:04.843: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

not sure if this is related.

I have tried various versions of `Gtk.main()`, `Gtk.main_quit()` and other ways to force the main loop, however, my (admittedly imperfect) reading is that file dialog implements the loops itself and does not need the main loop.

Anyone can help me to get this window to close?

I am using python 3.6.7, gi 3.26.1 on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I actually can't reproduce this. The dialog disappears immediately (which actually rather surprises me). I'm on Windows though; maybe that's why.

Comment: Thanks. Different platform may well explain it.  Which version of gi do you have?

Comment: I'm using Gtk 3.18.9.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works on my purpose.  Briefly, it involves GLib timeout that closes/hides the main window, and the Gtk.main() loop that does the window cleanup.  Here is the amended code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GLib
import time

def onTimeout():
    Gtk.main_quit()
    return False

win = Gtk.Window(title="test")

dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("World to load:", win,
                               Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
    (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
    Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
response = dialog.run()
if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
    print("load", dialog.get_filename())
else:
    print("cancel")

dialog.destroy()
GLib.timeout_add(100, onTimeout)
Gtk.main()
print("window closed, wait")

time.sleep(5)
```

I'd be happy to learn about a cleaner solution if someone can suggest one.  Forcing the main loop to do cleanup and timeout to leave it seems strange.

Comment: You can call `Gtk.main_quit()` right after `dialog.destroy()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply call

```
dialog.show()
```

after

```
dialog.destroy()
```

Sounds weird, but works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).